# Java throwing NullPointerException when loading Images using getClass().getResource()

Tags: java, image, jar

I have an Applet I'm trying to embed into a html file after packaging into a jar file.

Images are loaded in the main Applet Class with the following line

`return getImage(getClass().getResource("/../content/"+path));`

This works when running through eclipse but when I export it to a jar file I get a Null Pointer Exception. I've done some googling and I've tried to use getResourceAsStream with the following code

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
                 getClass().getResourceAsStream("/../content/"+path));
return ImageIO.read(is);
```

but this doesn't work through eclipse.

Content is the top level directory of the images and path is the specified path to the required image. The applet is in a folder called game, which is at the same level as content

Comment: try putting the content into the same package as the class thats accessing the content and change the paths accordingly and see if that helps. If it does, its a problem with your paths...

Comment: Thought so I see that if the resources are in their own path and package, but not in the current package, it never works out! even when you try go back a directory

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception/9866659#9866659) might can put more light on the topic :-)

Answer (score 3):

It was a comment now i answered it here (as OP said it did help): try putting the content into the same package as the class thats accessing the content and change the paths accordingly and see if that helps. If it does, its a problem with your paths.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But solved it using :-

```
<ClassName>.class.getClass().getResource(urlString);
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)
```

Also, your path looks a bit weird. /.. basically means the parent directory of the root, which cannot possibly work.